# textbox is not validated as empty if text is entered and then deleted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, placeholder

i have an annoying issue with watermarked text for a textbox.

what i want is if user click away of the textbox and there is no text in the textbox than the default text should appear (e.g. Search...)

i have this function to check it:

```
document.getElementById("searchtextbox").onblur = function() {

if (document.getElementById("searchtextbox").value == "") {
     document.getElementById("searchtextbox").setAttribute("value", "Search...");
}
```

it works great if i just click inside and click out. the problem comes when i click inside, enter text and delete it and then click outside.

i tried doing it with Length == 0, value == null, value.trim() == "", !value.match(/.+/) and none of them return true for this case.

Comment: in if condition use document.getElementById("searchtextbox").value="search";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bazmegakapa suggested, consider the `placeholder` attribute.

To answer your question, your code isn't working because you're using `setAttribute`, while the user just modified the property `value`. Instead of using `setAttribute`, try using `.value = 'Search...'`

Comment: I love you, been working on it for the past 2 hours and didn't understand am i doing wrong. using .value = "Search.." worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Please consider using **the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute**.

```
<input type="text" id="searchtextbox" placeholder="Search..." value="" />
```

As a lot of people under my answer pointed out, **Internet Explorer** won't be really keen on displaying your placeholder text (what a surprise). Still, it is way **more semantic** to use `placeholder`, and **do a feature detection** whether the browser supports it or not.

You can do feature detection like this (from [diveintohtml5.ep.io](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#input-placeholder)):

```
function supports_input_placeholder() {
  var i = document.createElement('input');
  return 'placeholder' in i;
}
```

If this is false, you can use your Javascript `placeholder` hack.

**UPDATE:** If you need help how to implement in a nice way, please refer to [Html placeholder text in a textarea form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021919/html-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea-form).

---

I also took a look at your code and fixed it:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/eu2wr/)

```
document.getElementById("searchtextbox").onblur = function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.value="Search...";
    }
}
```

Using `setAttribute` is not the right way here, you do not want to set the attribute, but the live property (`.value`). Your if condition actually worked, but the change was not reflected.

Comment: Not to sound snarky at all but do you really think it is a good idea to use HTML 5 with as little support that it has by browsers?

Comment: @naveen nor does it work for most versions of IE if it is HTML 5

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but i need it to work with IE6 and up.

Comment: @Omer Please see my edits. The best practice here is to provide the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute to browsers that support it, do a Javascript feature detection, and on failure provide a Javascript fallback solution for IE.

Comment: @Craig What do you mean by *little support*? Are you kidding? The newest version of every wide-spread browser has HTML5 support, including `placeholder`. How would you define *wide support* then?

Comment: IMO the solution you have provided is a lot of work for this feature and I do not feel there is nearly enough penetration for HTML 5 sorry. Quite surprised by the suggestion of it to be honest. Just my opinion bud!

Comment: @Craig Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 (which currently don't support it) will never support it :). Every other browser that has a significant usage percentage supports it. From your point of view, HTML5 should not be used for the next 6-7 years at least (can be more, depending on when will IE8 die). And I don't agree, it is some work ONCE to create a working `placeholder` fallback, and you can reuse it. From my experience, it is worth doing things **the right way**. Later this day I will update my answer with a bit more information.

Comment: We don't have to agree on this.

Comment: @Craig I did not say we have to :). But web development is a profession where you have to reevaluate your best practices regularly. It is evolving quite fast, and a good web developer should keep up and develop for the future as well.

Comment: Currently, there is no agreed upon standard for HTML 5 which is why I think it is foolish to jump on it. I think that the concept of HTML 5 standardization is great, but I simply don't think it's there yet. We don't have to agree on this.